# Libev on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, libevent, libev

Considering `libevent` vs. `libev`. Does the `libev` library have native support of IOCP on Windows?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

both libev and libevent use select on windows to detect and dispatch events (the event core doesn't do I/O, only events).

libevent in addition has a socket handle abstraction, which uses iocps on windows to do reads and writes. libev doesn't have anything comparable. the benchmarks seen so far indicate that the iocp backend of libevent is not very fast though, so if you are looking for fast on windows, you better do your own I/O at this point.

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at [libuv](https://github.com/joyent/libuv), yet another implementation of event loop. It supports IOCP and other backends.

This is robust because used by Node.JS.

Answer (score 3):

No, [it](http://cvs.schmorp.de/libev/ev_select.c?revision=1.55&view=markup) uses [select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740141%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)() , just as libevent does.

Comment: I guess they implemented IOCP in libevent, or at least they've tried.